# How to skip git check when running jest tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have my project in huge monorepo on non machine that has poor I/O performance etc. `git status` takes ages. When I run `npm test` (app was create with `create-react-app`), there's an initial step to that is determining tests to run. I assume that `jest` is figuring it out based on files changed.

Is there a way to configure jest to ignore `git` repo features completely and simply rerun all tests at startup and later run tests only for files that were affected by currently changed file (I guess that could be possible with `ES6` imports) or always rerun all tests when watched files are changed?